# _msearch returns nothing

Tags: elasticsearch

I created a Elasticsearch datasource in Grafana. Its config:

```
{
    "datasource": {
        "id": 4,
        "orgId": 1,
        "name": "Elasticsearch",
        "type": "elasticsearch",
        "typeLogoUrl": "",
        "access": "direct",
        "url": "http://localhost:9200/recipes",
        "password": "",
        "user": "",
        "database": "recipes",
        "basicAuth": false,
        "basicAuthUser": "",
        "basicAuthPassword": "",
        "withCredentials": false,
        "isDefault": true,
        "jsonData": {
            "esVersion": 77,
            "logLevelField": "",
            "logMessageField": "",
            "maxConcurrentShardRequests": 256,
            "timeField": "timestamp"
        },
        "secureJsonFields": {},
        "version": 25,
        "readOnly": false
    },
    "id": 4,
    "message": "Datasource updated",
    "name": "Elasticsearch"
}
```

And I noticed that Grafana makes OPTIONS requests this url for data:

```
http://localhost:9200/_msearch?max_concurrent_shard_requests=5
```

Without no data.

Could you say please how to get data from indexes?

P.S. Grafana of latest version. Elasticsearch of 7.7.0.

Answer (score 1):

[Multi search](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-multi-search.html) request have specific format

> The multi search API executes several searches from a single API
>   request. The format of the request is similar to the bulk API format
>   and makes use of the newline delimited JSON (NDJSON) format.

**Header :**

> (Required, object) Contains parameters used to limit or change the
>   subsequent search body request.This object is required for each search
>   body but can be empty ({}) or a blank line.

**Body :**

> (Optional, object) Contains parameters for a search request:

**Below is valid request**

```
GET recipes/_msearch?max_concurrent_shard_requests=5
{}
{}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using elasticsearch version 7.7, but your grafana datasource config show it is configured as it was using an older version, 5.6+

```
{
    "esVersion": 56,
    "logLevelField": "",
    "logMessageField": "",
    "maxConcurrentShardRequests": 256,
    "timeField": "timestamp"
 }
```

Try to change the version in your datasource config to 7.0+

Comment: thanx for answer. 
I see only OPTION requests to elasticsearch http://localhost:9200/_msearch?max_concurrent_shard_requests=5. I guess the requests must be GET?